# How to seperate the context log of each endpoint in springboot

Tags: java, spring, logging

I want to retrive the relative logs of a request from being received to the processing completed and respond.
Are there any solutions? thx.

eg . a request for fetch a user detail info. i want to collect the whole server processing logs

Comment: take a look into [spring-boot-sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth) it provides tracing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.